# css font-weight property not working with buttons

Tags: css, button, fonts

I have used 'ubuntu' font from google fonts.
I need font-weight: 300, but the font-weight property of button not working. it remains bold.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700&display=swap');
```

```
.btn {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Might be other CSS is overriding.  Can you please share URL for better understanding.

Comment: Use the browsers web console to inspect the elements applied stylings.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300!important;
}
```

Comment: Use of !important flag is not a good way. Maximum try to avoid use of it. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use !important on your styling, but it's generally not a good idea:

```
.btn {
    font-weight: 300 !important;
}
```

You could try to switch the order of the classes on your button so that .btn class overrides the .btn-primary class like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary btn">Primary</button>
```

OR, set a `<span>` element around the text you need to have font-weight on, to target it directly

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="boldz">Primary</span></button>
...
.boldz {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Hope one of these help!